# SceneKit drops to 40 FPS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Many times when I swipe iOS notifications from the top, and back to the app, then `SceneKit` fps drops to 40. Sometimes it happens also after minimising and maximising app. How come? Can this be overcome somehow? I tried pausing `SceneKit` when app becomes inactive, and resuming when it's back, but this is not helping.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior also: I have 2 scenes on the screen at a time, each with a single regular, slowly rotating, low poly sphere and a 400 x 200 texture on each of them.  I usually get a constant 120 fps but after I idle for a while or get a notification, the scenes stutter and get around 5 fps, even though Xcode says around 30.  I also tried scene.isPlaying = true to no avail.  However, I notice the cpu usage drops from ~50% to ~3%, like the app is throttling itself.  RAM stays constant at ~60 mb

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed this, too. In several different frameworks that use constant frame refreshing or are tied to the CADisplayLink as part of their presentation process.

I suspect, but have never been able to confirm, iOS is polling the performance of frame refreshing apps when they start, when they come out of inactive states, and when they're re-revealed after being obscured by system functions - like the notifications - and throttling to a guestimated rate without hiccups based on the polling results.

You can read more about my earlier thoughts on the matter here:
[SpriteKit scene with low fps on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841648/spritekit-scene-with-low-fps-on-start)

and here:

[Inconsistent SceneKit framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821033/inconsistent-scenekit-framerate)

There are many comments on similar experiences in SpriteKit, you can read here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14487

So it's not just SceneKit, and there's no apparent answer, and the problem varies in extent and nature between iOS versions, but has been lurking for many years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using CADisplayLink in one place of my app - removed it to see if it helps, but didn't. Anyway, looks like there is nothing we can do right now.

Comment: I also noted, that sometimes rotating the screen a few times helps, and SceneKit goes back to 60 fps.